# Can a javascript object have a property which is a collection of another type of object?

Tags: javascript, object, collections, properties

I have decided (whether bravely or foolishly remains to be seen) decided to increase my javascript skills beyond the use of alerts and I've
been looking at using javascript business objects with the hope of creating a useful library of objects that I can then manipulate with JSON or XML
further on down the line.

The basic concepts are straightforward enough but I can't seem to find an example anywhere of how to expose a property of an object that is a collection of
a different type of object.

For instance if I have a "Department" object I would like to have an "Employees" property which is a collection of "Employee" objects.

I'm from a .Net background so I might be coming at this with the completely wrong mindset here but if I am I'd like to learn the right way to approach this.

Is the concept still applicable in javascript, can a property of a javascript object be a collection of another type of object?  Does the concept of a collection even exist (I'd like to be able to enumerate through the collection too) or should I be thinking in terms of arrays or something else?

Here is some pseudo code which should illustrate what I'm aiming for:

```
function Department (Name) 
{
    this.DepartmentName=Name;
    this.Employees = null; // How do I initialise a property to be a collection of Employee objects?
    }

function Employee(FirstName, Surname)
{
    this.EmployeeName = Firstname + ' ' + Surname;
}

Department.prototype.addEmployee = function (Firstname, Surname) 
{
    //In here I want to create an Employee object and add it to an
    //'Employees' property of the department object
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no real "list of objects of a specific type" in JavaScript. You seem to just want an *array*, which is a "collection" (basically an object) with numeric keys and values which can be everything (JavaScript is dynamic, so there is no easy way to force a collection to contain only items of one type, but you should never need to anyway):

```
function Department (Name) 
{
    this.DepartmentName = Name;
    this.Employees = []; // empty array
}
```

Then in the prototype function, you can:

1. create a new instance (object) of type `Employee`
2. add it to `this.Employees`

Like:

```
Department.prototype.addEmployee = function (Firstname, Surname) 
{
    // adds to the end of the array
    this.Employees.push(new Employee(Firstname, Surname));
};
```

You can access the `Employee` objects like `this.Employees[0]`, etc.

Don't forget the semicolon at the end of the prototype function. It's a *function expression*, and it's good practice to terminate function expressions with a semicolon. *Function declarations* (like for `Department` and `Employee`), on the other hand, do not need those. The difference is that the prototype function is used as an expression in the assignment statement.

Moreover, `CapitalCase` is usually used for constructors (`Employee`); regular variable names are usually names in `camelCase`.

Comment: Thanks pimvdb, that fills in the blanks that I was struggling with perfectly.  I presume you just iterate through the employees by looping through the array by index then?

Comment: @Mordy: Yes, JavaScript's `for` loop is like most other languages - for an array usually `for(var i = 0; i < arrayName.length; i++) { ...do something with arrayName[i]... }`.

Comment: Excellent.  Thanks for your help :)

Comment: The statement that *expressions should be terminated with a semicolon* is not correct. Many expressions (e.g. those inside a grouping operator) and some statements (e.g. block statements) do not need to be terminated by a semi-colon. The rules for semi-colon insertion can't be summarised that simply, though they are usually required after statements (but not all statements). See ECMA-262 section 7.9.

Comment: @RobG: You're correct the current wording is not correct. I meant to describe the difference between a function expression and declaration.

Comment: The function expression in the example needs a terminating semi-colon because it is at the end of a statement. e.g. a semi-colon must not be inserted after the function expression in `alert(function(){return'hi';}());`, though one is required at the end of the statement it is part of (spaces deliberately removed).